# Raspberry Pi & Python 2.7 - trying to print to all users

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a program that runs when the Pi is booted.

The print statements are not displaying on additional terminal sessions.

I can only get the print statements when I kill the auto-booted process and restart the program.

Is there a method to broadcast print messages to all users - like the message displayed then typing 'Halt'?

Thx

Comment: What OS is installed on your Rasberry Pi?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `wall` BSD function.

> NAME
>        wall -- write a message to users
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        wall [-g group] [file]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The wall utility displays the contents of file or, by default, its standard input, on the terminals of all currently logged in users.